# Ridiculous 3 waysimultaneous equations need to get rid of $\lambda$ and find x and y

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations

$$x^2+8xy+7y^2-225=0
$$

$$2x+2\lambda x + 8\lambda y =0$$
$$2y+8\lambda x + 14 \lambda y = 0$$

So i need to equate for x and y by eliminating $\lambda$
i said $$x = \frac{-\lambda y}{2+2 \lambda }$$

$$y = \frac{-\lambda x}{2+14 \lambda }$$

From $f_x$ and $f_y$
 $$\lambda = \frac{-2x}{2x+8y}$$ 
 $$ \lambda = \frac{-2y}{8x+14y}$$

So solve...
$$ \frac{-2x}{2x+8y} = \ \frac{-2y}{8x+14y}$$
$$0=8y^2-8x^2-12yx$$

the remaining $xy$ really complicates things

Comment: I'm not sure if this will be much help, but the first equation may be factored and rearranged as:$(x+y)(x+7y)=225$

Comment: From the second equation, it follows that $$x=-\frac{8\lambda y}{2+2\lambda},$$ assuming that $\lambda \neq -1$.

Answer (score 1):

$0=8y^2−8x^2−12yx$

$0 = -4(2x-y)(x+2y)$

so $x=-2y$ or $x=y/2$ would give the solution